# How to use LDAP authentication in our app in android?

Tags: android, ldap

I want to add LDAP authentication in our application. I have searched and found two apps on Github, but they don't connect to server. What is a necessary condition to connect the server through ldap?

Answer (score 4):

Look into the UnboundID SDK. They have an kit for Android.

Source code for the app is available from [UnboundID in their LDAP SDK](https://github.com/pingidentity/ldapsdk/tree/master/android-ldap-client).

Comment: broken links. .

Answer (score 1):

You can find and example of authentication with ldap in [this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java)
and the android usage [here](http://www.dirmgr.com/blog/2009/3/24/using-ldap-on-android.html)