# How do I validate a Username and Password in an Active Directory from an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, authentication, active-directory, android-11

I am trying to validate an entered Username and Password in an Active Directory hosted on a Server inside my Network and then retrieving a single value from said user object. The User enters the Credentials on an Device running Android 11. The Device is connected to a Subnet within the Network. The application is coded in Java. I am using Android Studio as my IDE.

I would like to authenticate User credentials using an Active Directory and retrieve a single value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I do not have any code. I am trying to find a way to code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to connect directly to domain controllers (and not an AD-authenticated web site, for example), you can use NTLMv2 and LDAP.

This question is discussed here:

[How to use LDAP authentication in our app in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124111/how-to-use-ldap-authentication-in-our-app-in-android)

Specifically, here is detail for authenticating with the SDK mentioned above (though the above link includes others):

https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/getting-started/connections.html

If the user/password combination is valid, you'll get a success for the bindResponse.